# Git - only push up the most recent commit to github

Tags: git, github

On my local git repo I've got many commits, which include 'secret' connection strings :-)

I don't want this history on github when I push it there.

Essentially I want to push everything I have, but want to get rid of a whole lot of history.

Perhaps I would be better running in a branch for all my dev, then just merging back to master before committing... then the history for master will just be the commit I want.

I've tried running rebase:

```
git rebase –i HEAD~3
```

That went back 3 commits, and then I could delete a commit.

However ran into auto cherry-pick failed, and it got quite complex.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated... no big deal to can the history and start again if this gets too hard :-)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can branch your current work, rewind the master, then cherry-pick the latest commit back to the master:

```
git branch secret
git reset --hard HEAD~3
git cherry-pick secret
```

In pictures,

```
    A--B--C--D--E (master)
```

after `git branch secret`:

```
    A--B--C--D--E (master, secret)
```

after `git reset --hard HEAD~3`:

```
    A--B (master)
        \
         C--D--E (secret)
```

after `git cherry-pick secret`:

```
    A--B--E' (master)
        \
         C--D--E (secret)
```

Finally, if you `git checkout secret; git rebase master`, you can get:

```
    A--B--E' (master)
           \
            C--D (secret)
```

Comment: greatest git user i've ever seen

Comment: great stuff.. thanks very much Greg.  I would add for others that to resolve conflicts (the occured for me after cherrypicking) to use git mergetool

Comment: I like this .. How can I get to see this kind of pictorial representation of the state of branches?

Comment: @serengeti12: Well, I drew the above by hand. But, [`git show-branch`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-show-branch.html) gives a slightly more compact view in a vertical layout. Once you figure out how to read the output, it's quite helpful.

Comment: Thanks @GregHewgill.I mostly used git log --branch.I liked the horizontal layout, and thought there is a way to get that. I think It's easier to interpret

Answer (score 3):

## Scenario

You cloned a project and made a ridiculous amount of commits for a new feature, and the time has come to open source it or share it for review. And you don't want anyone to see your commit mess!

The original branch was `cloned_branch`, your messy commits were on `dev` branch, and you want to publish your clean work on the `public_branch` branch.

### Assume the following commits:

#### On branch `cloned_branch`:

> SHA0: Implemented X, and Y. (author:authorA)
>   SHA1: Implemented Z.        (author:authorA)
>   SHA2: Implemented W.        (author:authorA)

#### You created `dev` branch and pushed some commits:

> SHA3: trying to implement Q feature to work..
>   SHA4: shit, I doesn't work
>   SHA5: messed up even more! :(
>   SHA6: GOT IT WORKING!!!!
>   SHA7: cleanup!

#### Put all these changes in a single commit in `public_branch`:

```
git checkout SHA2 -b public_branch      # new branch at `authorA`'s last commit
git merge --squash SHA7        # squash commits up to your last one
git commit -m "Implemented Q (author:me)"
```

### Result:

Branches `cloned_branch` and `dev` remain as before, while`public_branch` branch contains:

> SHA0: Implemented X, and Y. (author:authorA)
>   SHA1: Implemented Z.        (author:authorA)
>   SHA2: Implemented W.        (author:authorA)
>   SHA8: Implemented Q.        (author:me)

Comment: What did happen to the SHA3 to 7. Does it lost ?

Comment: all these exist ONLY on the `dev` branch. `public_branch` essentially has different set of commits!

Comment: and if u wanna keep committing to `public_branch` you could use `git merge --squash dev `. Then accept changes from `dev` using: `git checkout --theirs <path>`, `git add <path>`, and commit to `public_branch`.
This will squash *ALL* commits from `dev`, from beginning.
each `public_branch` commit will be unrelated to `dev`, and will contain just the differences from it's previous commit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll post an answer.

If you have submodules, an approach similar to Paschalis' answer provides a more stable alternative (`cherry-pick` does not take submodules into account) and minimises conflicts (none in my case).

Here's my preferred approach:

```
git checkout OLDSHA -b temp
git merge --squash master
git commit -m "All my work"
```

Where `OLDSHA` is the oldest commit you feel safe to push to the public repository and `master` is the branch that contains all your work.

This creates a new branch (`temp`), which "hides" (by squashing) all history between `OLDSHA` and the most recent commit on `master`. The message for the new commit will be "All my work".

You can then **delete** master and make temp the new master (before doing this, make sure master has been safely pushed to another repository or backed up)

```
git branch -d master
git branch -m temp master
```

And push to a new remote, keeping your old remote intact

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin NEW_URL
git push --set-upstream origin master
```