# git push to remote and lose all history

Tags: eclipse, git

I have a git project that I'm about to push to SourceForge. The origin for my local repo is a shared file system repo that gives me a backup facility.

When I eventually add SF as another remote I just want to push the latest (= versioned) commit to it as the starting base of my code on that repo, and not include all the previous commits that contain possibly rubbish/sensitive/embarrassing code.

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276686/git-only-push-up-the-most-recent-commit-to-github), except that question was about just leaving out some of the history - I want to leave out *all* of the history and have the latest commit to become the starting point of the project code on SF. Importantly, having done this, I want "push to upstream" to continue to work even though origin and SF will be different.

Is this possible? Incidentally I'm doing this through Eclipse ie. eGit.

**Update**

My original question should have been clearer, although the answers so far have helped clarify exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

I want just consolidated commits pushed to SF, representing the published versions. 
This is what I want to do:

```
[master]  A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I... --> push to origin (private)
                 \           \
[public]         V1----------V2...     --> push to public remote repo
```

`@michas's` answer starts me off with V1 on branch public, but I can't figure out how to continue to extend this branch with subsequent version commits. I've experimented with rebase but can't get the result I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided by @michas didn't allow me to subsequently maintain the branch with consolidated history. This required the use of git merge --squash. The scheme I eventually came up with was similar to the one [described here](http://www.braintreepayments.com/braintrust/our-git-workflow).

Just tidying up so the question has an upvoted answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to start with a new repo.  Why don't you just delete or rename your old repo and create a brand new one.  Then copy all of your files in, commit them, and push.

Comment: I don't want to lose the history locally or in origin, just on SourceForge.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot push the current commit, as this commit contains the whole "rubbish" history.

However you can create a new commit with the same content but without any history.

```
git checkout --orphan fresh  # create a new branch called `fresh` without any history
git commit                   # add your work as a new commit
git diff fresh master        # the both branches should contain the same content (assuming you original branch was called `master`)
git log                      # verify the current branch does not contain any history
git push sf fresh            # push that branch
git push sf fresh:master     # (or you might want to call that branch master on sf)
```